# Finding gradient of $\det(\mathbf{\Sigma})^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ with respect to $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ (a Covariance matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

In the book `Mathematics for Machine Learning` (chapter on Gaussian Mixture Models), I got stuck trying to figure out how they came up with

$$\frac{\partial \det(\mathbf{\Sigma})^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{\partial \mathbf{\Sigma}} = \frac{-1}{2}\det(\mathbf{\Sigma})^\frac{-1}{2} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}$$

where $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is the covariance matrix. The book mentions that the following identity was used:
$$\frac{\partial \det(f(\mathbf{X}))}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \det(f(\mathbf{X}))Trace\left( f(\mathbf{X})^{-1} \frac{\partial f(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \mathbf{X}} \right)$$

But the question is, how did they use it to arrive at the first equation ? I can't seem to figure it out. Been stuck for quite a while.

Thanks!

Comment: How is an $f$ on scalars such as $\det X$ defined on a matrix such as $X$?

Comment: @J.G. using Taylor series

Comment: Also, isn't the more general equation's RHS a scalar?

Comment: I really don't understand why in the first equation the right side is matrix, but in the second one the right side is scalar...

Comment: @J.G. My bad. I did a typo (got it in reverse order). Fixing it

Comment: Your edit still doesn't fix the general identity's matrix-scalar disparity.

Comment: @J.G. It didn't ? Weird. I wrote what's written in the book (https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf) See page numbered 158 (Section 5.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easier to work with the logarithmic form of the [Jacobi formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial \log\det X}{\partial X} &= X^{-T}
 &\quad\big({\rm assuming\;}\det X > 0\big) \\
}$$
and to use $S=\Sigma\;$ for ease of typing.
$$\eqalign{
c &= (\det S)^{-1/2}
 &\qquad\qquad&\big({\rm Cost\;function}\big) \\
\log(c) &= -\tfrac 12\log(\det S)\\
\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial c}{\partial S} &= -\tfrac 12S^{-T}
 &\qquad&\big({\rm Logarthmic\;derivative=Jacobi}\big) \\
\frac{\partial c}{\partial S} &= -\tfrac 12cS^{-1}
 &\qquad&\big(S\,{\rm \,is\,symmetric}\big) \\
}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two parts: an apparent matrix/scalar mismatch in the general result, and how to choose and substitute a suitable $f$. To address the first part, I'll assume your $\operatorname{Tr}$ shouldn't be in the general result; after all, you've already edited it out of the special case of interest. So onto the second part: if we take $f(y)=y^{-1/2}$ so $f^\prime(y)=-\tfrac12y^{-3/2}$, the putative identity gives$$\partial_\Sigma(\det \Sigma)^{-1/2}=\det(\Sigma^{-1/2})\operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma^{1/2}\cdot-\tfrac12\Sigma^{-3/2})=-\tfrac12(\det\Sigma)^{-1/2}\Sigma^{-1}.$$